# Excel - make a sum with some criterias

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

- -----A  ------B------------C
- 1||Name    ||31-03-13     ||1-04-13
- 2||test1   ||>>>>     150 ||>>>> 10
- 3||test2   ||>>>>     750 ||>>>> 11
- 4||test3   ||>>>>     800 ||>>>> 12
- 5||test3   ||>>>>     900 ||>>>> 13

I want write in a cell the date, in another cell the name and sum the values

Ex:
Name: test3
Date: 31-03-13
And it should sum 800+900.

Someone can help me?

Comment: Posting a screenshot of an Excel sheet with the data entered, with Cell locators visible (like A1, G6, etc), might help provide a better answer here.

Comment: I can't.... is my 1st post.... :(

Answer (score 1):

Given a data setup like this:

[image: tigeravatar sumif with index]

The formula in cell G2 and copied down is:

```
=IF(OR(E2="",F2="",COUNTIF($B$1:$C$1,F2)=0),"",SUMIF($A$2:$A$5,E2,INDEX($B$2:$C$5,0,MATCH(F2,$B$1:$C$1,0))))
```

Alternately, you could use a pivot table.

Comment: Many many thanks!!!! Is exactly that I need! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You need [SUMIF](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/sumif-HP005209292.aspx).

Try something like `=SUMIF(A1:A5, "=test3", B1:B5)`

Comment: I have done like that, but is giving some problems with the range. I would only select the date and I would not "forced" to put the range manualy